# AWS Transit Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, gateway, vpc

We have 1 environment with a lot of services on 1 amazon account.
We are using NAT gateways and our ec2 instances have private ip (10.0.0.0/16).

Questions: 
If we will use Transit gateway is it possible to create new aws account, connect 2 accounts via transit gateway and route traffic from second account via our NAT gateways?

Comment: Clarify the last part of the question.  Are you looking to have network traffic from both accounts use the second accounts NAT Gateway?

Comment: Yes, i need that all ec-2 instances go though my NAT gateway.
For example i have 5 amazon accounts and all ec2 go via NAT gateway with 
one static IP via NAT gateway that working only on 1 account

Answer (score 1):

Yes we set something similar up using our AWS Landing Zone.  If you're doing it from scratch you'll have to use AWS Resource Access Manager to share the transit gateway either directly with another AWS Account or if you're in an ORG, with your whole ORG.  Then it's just a matter of creating the appropriate associations and routing tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is one of the supported use cases.  Please note that you would have to add in your TGW prefixes VPC route table so that the traffic can make it back to the transit gateway when returning from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Bald Monkey. Stress on the "manually" need to add and maintain your VPC routes with TGW. (I'm not yet able to comment in StackOverflow, so couldn't just add it to above. Still, I'm a better looking chimp than a Bald Monkey :-D ).